# How to make width of nested CSS elements all the same?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my implementation of some HTML and CSS that I created. I am having trouble with the width of some buttons within my container `div`. I want it so that somehow I can always ensure that `width` of the button elements are always 50% of what the div that it is in. This is the image I wanted to recreate:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/2z3C3Z0L2Q0R282p1V0z/Image%202014-12-19%20at%2010.07.09%20AM.png

Here is my attempt:

```css
/* Global resets */
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
button { 
  font-family: "rooney-sans", Avenir-Book, Calibri, sans-serif;
}
body {font-family: "rooney-sans", Avenir-Book, Calibri, sans-serif; color: #424242; line-height: 1.4;}

/* Fonts */
h1 {
  font-family: "rooney-web", 'AmericanTypewriter', Rockwell, serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  margin: 2em auto;
  max-width: 630px;
  text-align: center;
}

.funding-text {
  border: 1px solid;
}

/* Our entire container */
.funding-box {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 265px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* Our input box */
input.giving-input{
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}

.give {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

p .days-left{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EF5F3C;
}

.padded-text {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
}

button, input {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.give-button{
  background-color: #1CBC2C;
  color: white;
  border-color: #1CBC2C;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  visited: false;
}

a:visited {
  color: blue;
}

.chat-bubble {
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.funding-rate {
  background-color: #EF5F3C;
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.save-button, .share-button {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 125px;
}

.share-button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">      
  <div class="funding-box">
    <div class="chat-bubble"><b>$167</b> still needed for this project</div>
    <div class="funding-text">
      <div class="funding-rate"></div>
      <div class="padded-text">
        <p><span class="days-left">Only 3 days left</span> to fund this project.<br/><br/> Join the <b>42</b> other doners who have already supported this project. Every dollar helps.</p>
        <span class="give">
          <input class="giving-input" type="text" value="$50">
          <button class="give-button">Give now</button>
        </span>
      <a href=""><i>Why give $50?</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="give"> 
      <button class="save-button">Save for later</button>
      <button class="share-button">Tell your friends</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is with the `save-button` and `share-button`, but also the `give-button` and `giving-input` classes. I don't necessarily want to hard code the width here to make it so that they align properly. Rather, if there is a programmatic way so that I can set them to `width: 50%` of the parent `div`, as opposed to hard coding the widths that would be great. I tried to set the class `.give {width: 100%}` and then set the `.giving-input, .give-button, .save-button, .share-button: {width: 50%}` but that didn't work for me. Any tips or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does java script will do? you can set half of the outbox div's width, even thought your boxes are outside of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set all inputs/buttons width to `49%` and remove the `margin-left` you had there everything should work (I also changed one of your containers from `inline-block` back to `block` to make sure it takes 100% of the width).

Here is the fix to your code:

```css
/* Global resets */
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
button { 
  font-family: "rooney-sans", Avenir-Book, Calibri, sans-serif;
}
body {font-family: "rooney-sans", Avenir-Book, Calibri, sans-serif; color: #424242; line-height: 1.4;}

/* Fonts */
h1 {
  font-family: "rooney-web", 'AmericanTypewriter', Rockwell, serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  margin: 2em auto;
  max-width: 630px;
  text-align: center;
}

.funding-text {
  border: 1px solid;
}

/* Our entire container */
.funding-box {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 265px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* Our input box */
input.giving-input{
  width: 49%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}

.give {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

p .days-left{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EF5F3C;
}

.padded-text {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
}

button, input {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.give-button{
  background-color: #1CBC2C;
  color: white;
  border-color: #1CBC2C;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 49%;
}

a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  visited: false;
}

a:visited {
  color: blue;
}

.chat-bubble {
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.funding-rate {
  background-color: #EF5F3C;
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.save-button, .share-button {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 125px;
}

.share-button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">      
  <div class="funding-box">
    <div class="chat-bubble"><b>$167</b> still needed for this project</div>
    <div class="funding-text">
      <div class="funding-rate"></div>
      <div class="padded-text">
        <p><span class="days-left">Only 3 days left</span> to fund this project.<br/><br/> Join the <b>42</b> other doners who have already supported this project. Every dollar helps.</p>
        <span class="give">
          <input class="giving-input" type="text" value="$50" />
          <button class="give-button">Give now</button>
        </span>
      <a href=""><i>Why give $50?</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="give"> 
      <button class="save-button">Save for later</button>
      <button class="share-button">Tell your friends</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. This is great. Just wondering then, is the `49%` width for both the `input` and the `button` then because they should take up `98%` of the total parent div, and then the 2% is left over for the space in between the `input` and the `button`?

Answer (score 0):

you can split that in to 2 pieces ,each have width 50%.but here also applying a padding of 10px ,so you can use the function `calc(50% - 10px);` to get the exact value.

```css
/* Global resets */
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
button { 
  font-family: "rooney-sans", Avenir-Book, Calibri, sans-serif;
}
body {font-family: "rooney-sans", Avenir-Book, Calibri, sans-serif; color: #424242; line-height: 1.4;}

/* Fonts */
h1 {
  font-family: "rooney-web", 'AmericanTypewriter', Rockwell, serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  margin: 2em auto;
  max-width: 630px;
  text-align: center;
}

.funding-text {
  border: 1px solid;
}

/* Our entire container */
.funding-box {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 265px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* Our input box */
input.giving-input{
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}

.give {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

p .days-left{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EF5F3C;
}

.padded-text {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
}

button, input {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.give-button{
  background-color: #1CBC2C;
  color: white;
  border-color: #1CBC2C;
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
}
a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  visited: false;
}

a:visited {
  color: blue;
}

.chat-bubble {
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.funding-rate {
  background-color: #EF5F3C;
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.save-button, .share-button {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 125px;
}

.share-button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">      
  <div class="funding-box">
    <div class="chat-bubble"><b>$167</b> still needed for this project</div>
    <div class="funding-text">
      <div class="funding-rate"></div>
      <div class="padded-text">
        <p><span class="days-left">Only 3 days left</span> to fund this project.<br/><br/> Join the <b>42</b> other doners who have already supported this project. Every dollar helps.</p>
        <span class="give">
          <input class="giving-input" type="text" value="$50">
          <button class="give-button">Give now</button>
        </span>
      <a href=""><i>Why give $50?</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="give"> 
      <button class="save-button">Save for later</button>
      <button class="share-button">Tell your friends</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```